# Using Javascript to extract part of a string

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript, and have been struggling to find a proper way to do what I'm looking for.
I have a heading "Page: Lastname Firstname"

What I want to do, is grab the last name ~only~ 
The last name will vary by length, and the page name will change as well but the format will always stay the same.

Comment: Can the last name ever be more than one word?  What about the first name?  Also, would a middle name ever be present?

Comment: Please show us some example or what have you tried so far.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - The last name would always be in format of YY-XXXXXXXX or XXXXXX (never 2 words, only a hyphen). First name will never have a space or any special character and never a middle name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const pageTitle = 'Page: Lastname Firstname'
const lastName = pageTitle.split(' ')[1]
```

Basically we are splitting `pageTitle` string into Array, using  as separator. And then we are accessing second `[1]` element of given Array.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the format will remain like `Name: fname lname`. There is no middle name of something else. You can use `split()` by `' '` and get second element.

```js
let str = "Page: Lastname Firstname"
console.log(str.split(' ')[1])
```